# Logistic regression - When to include or exclude a confounding variable from the model?

Tags: biostatistics, confounding, multivariate-regression

I am working on determining if there is an association between a medication (yes/no) and a health outcome (yes/no).

However, the lines between what is a confounding variable to include in the model, and what is a known risk factor that should dictate who is included or excluded from the study cohort, are becoming blurred.

For example, antibiotics are a known risk factor for this health outcome. Thus, there are several studies identical to mine that exclude people from their study cohort if they took an antibiotic within a certain time frame.

However, prior hospitalization is also a known risk factor, yet I have seen some studies identical to mine handle it by excluding everyone who was hospitalized within a certain time frame from their study cohort, whereas some include prior hospitalization as an independent variable.

How should I approach these types of variables?

Comment: Your question I think is more about experimentation than about the inference algorithm

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of what hypothesis you want to test and the population to which you want to apply your results.

Take the example of whether or not to include those who took an antibiotic. If you exclude those who took an antibiotic then your results will only apply to those who didn't it. If you include those who took an antibiotic then you can, in principle, extend your results to a wider population, evaluate whether taking an antibiotic by itself is associated with the health outcome, and whether the association of the medication of primary interest with that outcome differs depending on having received an antibiotic. That's a more complicated model, however, and might require a larger study population to get clean results.

The choice is thus based on your goals and your understanding of the subject matter.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to infer whether a treatment has an effect on an outcome of interest, you need a randomized control trial (RCT); if this is not possible, in some use-cases, causal inference algorithms, such as synthetic control, can be of use, but I do not believe that your situation is applicable.

If certain factors prevent a person from exposure to the treatment, then ideally these factors would be missing from both treatment and control groups. (One strategy is to recruit and give the control group placebos.)

However, if you’re unable to ensure that a certain factor is orthogonal to treatment exposure then the factor becomes correlated with the treatment; in consequence, you’re estimating the interaction of treatment and factor, not the treatment, in isolation.

Suppose that comparing surgery methods, a new proposed method against the established method. And you’re interested in whether the new method has a faster recovery time. If antibiotics suppresses the immune system, and antibiotics is removed from treatment group but not control group, then there’s a negative correlation between treatment and antibiotics, confounding your conclusions about recovery times.

If antibiotics is completely removed the study, then you cannot condition on it in your logistic regression model (always zero.)

I would be interested in the effect of antibiotics on recovery times and would want to randomize such that antibiotics was equally prevalent in treatment and control groups (orthogonal to treatment exposure.) this way you could infer the effects of both antibiotics and treatment effect, decoupled from one another.

But if the risk to safety is too high, you must remove it from both groups and cannot condition on it in your model.

On the topic of synthetic control, the idea is to synthesize Frankenstein samples from your “control” group for comparison with your treatment group. Suppose that height is a factor of interest and in your treatment group, you have an individual of 5’ tall but no such member in the control group; however, there are individuals that are 4’ and 6’ tall. If height is the only factor, synthetic control would average these two response variable observations for to synthesize what would have happened if the 5’ individual in the treatment group did not receive the treatment (the counterfactual.)

All this to say, synthetic control cannot help you if your treatment group has zero antibiotics and your control group has some non-zero antibiotics.

(To give more context, Synthetic Control is used heavily on economics where it's impractical or unethical to execute an RCT.)

Comment: Synthetic control is like taking a sledgehammer to drive a nail. There may be more appropriate tools for OP’s case and you should first suss out if those can be used.

Comment: @DemetriPananos did you miss 75% of my answer?